# Fetching Data to the Wirecloud

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I’m trying to use the ‘**ngsi-source-operator**’ to fetch data from ‘**Orion context broker**’ and trying to populate that data on the Map Widget.

My Orion instance is running @ http://130.206.117.237:1026 and I’m using the global instance of wirecloud.

What setting should I use for NGSI-source-operator in order to fetch data?
Also while creating subscriptions, which URL should I use to send the notifications?

Comment: Looking for similar resource too.